# ReactJS map onClick get value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im new to React, and im creating an app that will fetch the values with an onClick event, I figured that I'd do something liket this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Ingredients extends Component {
// Functions
clickIngredient() {
let val = this.refs.itemValue.value;
console.log(val);
}
render() {
  // Print out all ingredients through mapping
  // First create var from props
  const ingredients = this.props.data;
  // Now map through it
  const ingredientList = ingredients.map((item, i) => {
  // Return listitem
  return (
    <li key={i} ref="itemValue" value={item} onClick={this.clickIngredient.bind(this)}>{item}</li>
  );
});
// Final view
return (
  <div className="ingredients">
    <ul className="ingredient-list">
      {ingredientList}
    </ul>
  </div>
  )
 }
}

export default Ingredients;
```

But I do not get the value, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`li` elements do not have a `value` property.  Try this:

Set `data-value` attribute instead of `value`.  Retrieve it via `dataset.value` instead of `value`.  And instead of trying to set a `ref`, just use the `target` property of the click event to get to the `li` element.

Also, this version shows how to bind `clickIngredient` once instead of once for each list item (thanks to @Joshua Slate for the suggestion).

```
class Ingredients extends Component {
  clickIngredient = (ev) => {
    let val = ev.target.dataset.value;
    console.log(val);
  };
  render() {
    // Print out all ingredients through mapping
    // First create var from props
    const ingredients = this.props.data;
    // Now map through it
    const ingredientList = ingredients.map((item, i) => {
    // Return listitem
    return (
      <li key={i} data-value={item} onClick={this.clickIngredient}>{item}</li>
    );
    });
    // Final view
    return (
      <div className="ingredients">
        <ul className="ingredient-list">
          {ingredientList}
        </ul>
      </div>
      )
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Brandon

Comment: To add to this, you should either add a constructor and bind clickIngredient in the constructor, or simply make clickIngredient an arrow function. Then your onClick would be this.clickIngredient.

Comment: passing value as function argument i much better way in this case.

Comment: @Ved that method is very expensive in terms of memory and re-render speed.  You are creating a new scoped function for each item in the list, and on re-render you recreate the functions and trigger rebinding of the event handlers.  Binding event handler functions to array items is not recommended when rendering an array of items in react.

Comment: @Brandon Can you point me to some documentation or benchmarks about that?

Answer (score 1):

I wonder why you have not passed value as arguments to function.
Like: `onClick={this.clickIngredient.bind(this,item)}`

Solution:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Ingredients extends Component {
// Functions
clickIngredient(value) {
let val = value;
console.log(val);
}
render() {
  // Print out all ingredients through mapping
  // First create var from props
  const ingredients = this.props.data;
  // Now map through it
  const ingredientList = ingredients.map((item, i) => {
  // Return listitem
  return (
    <li key={i} ref="itemValue" value={item} onClick={this.clickIngredient.bind(this,item)}>{item}</li>
  );
});
// Final view
return (
  <div className="ingredients">
    <ul className="ingredient-list">
      {ingredientList}
    </ul>
  </div>
  )
 }
}

export default Ingredients;
```